# How can I override the style attribute in a div with CSS?

Tags: css

I usually add !important but for some reason, it doesn't work with this:

```
<div id="page" class="site" style="padding-top: 206px;">
```

My CSS code:

```
div#page.site {
    padding-top: 0px!important;
}
```

I also tried this but to no avail:

```
div#page.site[style] {
        padding-top: 0px;
    }
```

Comment: Add space between 0px and !important

did this fix it?

Comment: it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/n7beodcu/

Comment: _“it doesn't work with this”_ - yes it does, as https://jsfiddle.net/thmuap05/ shows. You need to make the effort to provide an _actual_ [mre] in questions like this.

Comment: No, we don’t want to just be pointed to your external page either - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-website-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: div#page.site {
    padding-top: 0px!important;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increase the specificity as well as make the property important.

```
div#page.site[style] {
    padding-top: 0px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div #page .site[style]{padding-top: 0px !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will leave this for others who might see it:

**DO NOT USE IMPORTANT!**

> Using !important, however, is bad practice and should be avoided
> because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural
> cascading in your stylesheets. When two conflicting declarations with
> the !important rule are applied to the same element, the declaration
> with a greater specificity will be applied.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#the_!important_exception